# google drive api search query by Date

Tags: search, google-drive-api

Trying to get files from bydate
**q=createdDate=2012-06-04** not working. sure doing something wrong, but didnt find any example for it.
please advice.

Comment: Do you use Drive API v2? For Drive API v2, you cannot use ``createdDate`` as a field. You can use ``modifiedTime``. If you use ``modifiedTime``, the query string is ``q=modifiedDate%3D'2012-06-04'``. ``%3D`` is ``=``. But, for Drive API v3, you can use ``q=createdTime%3D'2012-06-04'``. In this case, this is not ``createdDate``.

Comment: i'm using v3 php and js apis

Comment: Hey, could you please give an example for request? thanks

Comment: You can see the sample scripts from here. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk Please check the Quickstarts.

Comment: i did. nothing there ( other things are, but not one i'm searching for